# Extrair valor HTML

Tags: php, regex, libcurl

Recebo o html e uma parte dele de onde que preciso extrair os dados e esse aqui

```
         <td class="address-list-item">
    NOme silva    <div class="modal-content" style="display:none;">
        <div class="address-list-modal">
            <h2 class="title title-5">Excluir endereço</h2>
            <h3 class="title title-7">Deseja realmente excluir esse endereço?</h3>

            <div class="address-default-title">NOme</div>
            <div class="address-default-item">Rua  </div>
            <div class="address-default-item">CEP - SETOR </div>
            <div class="address-default-item">Cidade - Estado</div>

            <a onclick="deleteAddress(00000)" class="btn btn-9" "="" href="javascript::void(0)">Sim</a>
            <a onclick="clModal()" class="btn btn-9" href="javascript::void(0)">Não</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="address-list-item">

    Rua  -
    cep - setor -
    Cidade - Estado
</td>
<td class="address-list-item">
    (00) 0000-0000    </td>
                        <td class="address-list-item is-last">
                            <a class="sel-link-edit-addicional-0000 address-list-item-link" href="/customer/address/edit/?address_id=000">
                                Editar                            </a>
                            <span class="bt_separator">|</span>
                            <a id="bt-delete-0000" class="address-list-item-link" href="javascript::void(0)" onclick="confirmationModal(this,0000)">
                                Excluir                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

e preciso extrair apenas o  Cidade - Estado

então fiz a minha regex assim

```
    if (preg_match("#- (.*?) - \b[A-Z][A-Z]#", $this->http_response, $match))
    $estado = $match[0];

return $estado;
```

só que não está retornando a Cidade - Estado , e já todos assunto relacionado ao assunto no stackoverfolow e não encontrei nada que posso me ajuda nesse problema :/

Comment: a ER que tentou montar não faz sentido.. mas de qualquer forma, é complicado pois não tem uma referência lógica de identificação do trecho que deseja extrair. O que sugiro é, caso os dados retornem sempre na mesma linha, vc poderia apenas ir direto a linha correspondente... Acho que assim seria muito mais fácil porque pegando a linha, bastaria dar um explode() para separar Estado e Cidade.. Isso é uma mera sugestão.. há outros meios para resolver, inclusive com ER, mas prefiro recomendar o modo mais simples

Comment: Ou você pode utilizar um _parser_, que também facilita muito a vida, por exemplo: [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) ou o http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Answer (score 1):

Se o campo **sempre** vem formatado assim:

```
Rua  -
cep - setor -
Cidade - Estado
```

Você pode usar a função explode do PHP

```
$endereco = explode ( '-' , endereco );
$cidade = $endereco[2];
$estado = $endereco[3];
```

ou javascript:

```
var endereco = document.querySelector(".address-list-item").innerHTML.split("-");
var rua = endereco[0];
var cep = endereco[1];
var cidade = endereco[2];
var estado = endereco[3];
```